# Fluttter: Google Maps: Quitar botones por defecto de los marcadores

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Necesito ayuda con esto, estoy trabajando en flutter y quería saber si existe alguna manera de quitar esos botones que aparecen por defecto cuando presionas un marcador(Los que aparecen en la esquina inferior derecha), o no hay manera, agradezco su ayuda por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El plugin no tiene expuesto ese método, así que por defecto siempre aparece,  el método en cuestión es el `setMapToolbarEnabled`

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)

Por defecto está en true.

Por ejemplo en el caso de Android, no hay un método el cual permita poner eso en falso:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/GoogleMapController.java